# String to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a string example

```
"abc|pqr[abc,xyz[abc,def]]"
```

Now i want to output into array

```
{
   abc : true,
   pqr : ['abc', xyz : [abc, def]]
}
```

the code i wrote is this but it give me 
`"message": "Maximum call stack size exceeded"`

```
var x = 'p[a,b,c,d]|q[small,large]|r[small,large]|s|t[w[x,y],z[a,b,c]]';
y = x.split("|");
function foo(query) {
        if (typeof query == "string") query = [query]
        var i = {}
        _(query).forEach(function(v) {
            regexQuery = v.match(/\[(.*)\]/);
            if (regexQuery != null) {
                index = regexQuery['index']
                if (regexQuery[1].match(/\[(.*)\]/) != null) {
                    i[regexQuery['input'].substr(0, index)] = foo(regexQuery[0])
                } else {
                    i[regexQuery['input'].substr(0, index)] = regexQuery[1].split(",");
                }
            } else {
                i[v] = true;
            }
        })
        return i;
    }
console.log(foo(y));
```

i know regex is not got for this but is there any other solution?

Comment: please add the wanted result of the conversion if `x`. btw, why is a `:` necessary and why is it not in the first string `abc|pqr[abc,xyz[abc,def]]`?

Comment: Is there some good reason you're using an invented data structure?

Comment: I just edited the question removed colon (:), was testing in some different cases @NinaScholz first string only

Comment: @Utkanos yes build up an API so it can be parameter driven.

Comment: You'll pull your hair out just testing this code. You initial input is very close to json format. Is there any chance to change it to json format?

Comment: you first example is no valid javascript. you can not have a property in an array

Comment: @FaizanHasan developing an API is fine, but that doesn't necessitate inventing a data format. Unless you have good reason not to use JSON, I'd think about converting. Otherwise you're just making work for yourself.

Comment: I really don't understand your example of the before and after.  Like @NinaScholz said, it's not valid JavaScript.  You have `xyz: [abc, def]` as one of the elements in the array.  Did you mean to wrap that in `{}` and forget to put quotes around `"abc"` and `"def"`?

Comment: In 1st example why is abc true? How did you derive true? What about the expected output for 2nd example? I guess you'll have to tell us the expected results before we can determine whether regex is a good approach or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function below. For the input given in the question:

```
p[a,b,c,d]|q[small,large]|r[small,large]|s|t[w[x,y],z[a,b,c]]
```

...it produces this object:

```
{
  "p": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d"
  ],
  "q": [
    "small",
    "large"
  ],
  "r": [
    "small",
    "large"
  ],
  "s": true,
  "t": {
    "w": [
      "x",
      "y"
    ],
    "z": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]
  }
}
```

```js
function toObject(x) {
    // Turn custom format into JSON text format, and then parse it.
    // In that object, find nested objects that could be turned into array.
    return (function flagsToArray(obj) {
        // Collect keys with nested objects.
        var nested = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] !== true);
        // For those, call this function recursively
        nested.forEach(key => obj[key] = flagsToArray(obj[key]));
        // If no nesting, then turn this into an array
        return nested.length ? obj : Object.keys(obj);
    })(JSON.parse('{' + 
        x.replace(/\|/g, ',') // treat '|' as ','
         .replace(/"/g, '\"') // escape any double quotes
         .replace(/([^,|\[\]]+)/g, '"$1"') // wrap terms in double quotes
         .replace(/"\[/g, '":[') // insert colon for assignment of arrays
         .replace(/"([,\]])/g, '":true$1') // insert `true` assignment for atomic term
         .replace(/\[/g, "{").replace(/\]/g, "}") // replace array notation with object notation
        + '}'));
}

// Sample input
var x = 'p[a,b,c,d]|q[small,large]|r[small,large]|s|t[w[x,y],z[a,b,c]]';
// Convert
var obj = toObject(x);
// Output
console.log(obj);
```

The function makes several replacements to convert the custom format into a JSON text format, turning everything into nested objects (no arrays). Then in a second process, a recursive one, objects are identified that have no nested objects, i.e. they only consist of members with `true` as value. Those objects are then replaced by their array "equivalent", i.e. the array with the object's keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your query string is essentially a flat representation of a tree whose nodes are defined by:

- either a name alone
- or a name and a list of child nodes

Note that I don't see any obvious difference between `,` and `|`, so I'm going to assume that they actually have the same meaning.

You can't easily store this structure by using only arrays, and it would also be unnecessarily complicated to use a mix of arrays and objects.

Therefore, I'd suggest to use only objects with the following conventions:

- key = name of node
- value = either *true*<sup>1</sup> or a child object

1 *<sub>This is a placeholder. You may also consider using an empty object.</sub>*

With these assumptions, your example string `"abc|pqr[abc,xyz[abc,def]]"` would be decoded as:

```
tree = {
  "abc": true,
  "pqr": {
    "abc": true,
    "xyz": {
      "abc": true,
      "def": true
    }
  }
}
```

Such a structure is quite easy to manipulate.

For instance, if you'd like to get the child nodes of `root > pqr > xyz`, you could do:

```
Object.keys(tree.pqr.xyz)
```

which will return:

```
["abc", "def"]
```

## Implementation

Below is a possible implementation:

```js
function parse(query) {
  var n, tree = {}, node = tree, stk = [],
      sym = '', sz = (query += ',').length;

  for(n = 0; n < sz; n++) {
    switch(query[n]) {
      case '|':
      case ',':
        sym && (node[sym] = true);
        break;

      case '[':
        stk.push(node);
        node = node[sym] = {};
        break;

      case ']':
        sym && (node[sym] = true);
        node = stk.pop();
        break;

      default:
        sym += query[n];
        continue;
    }
    sym = '';
  }
  return tree;
}

console.log(parse("abc|pqr[abc,xyz[abc,def]]"));
```